# Secure way to call the API from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I'm using flask to build my API. I've a tornado server in front of flask which takes care of requests. I'm using HTTP basic auth in Flask like this:

```
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

@auth.get_password
def get_password(username):
    if username == 'uname':
        return 'password'
    return None
```

And this is how I'm calling the API from my Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
            url: api_url + 'customer',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,

            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(uname + ":" + password)
            },

            data: {start: start_date, end: end_date},
            success: function(result) {
                data = result.results;
            }
         });
```

I realize that this isn't exactly secure (since the front end JS file has "username" and "password" in it) so my question is how do I make it secure? What's the correct way to make API requests?

Comment: Ultimately, you're sending the plain password over anyway. If you want to do some client-side hashing it might help but it'd be the same if you're using a form. If you want, you can pop open the Network tab of your console and check how requests are made.

Comment: Use `post` so that it goes encrypted, and use the `cache: false` option for ajax.

Comment: sounds good - will definitely do that. thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant avoid sending your password this way and it's fine. You just need to take reasonable precautions about how those credentials are handled. Make sure you are not saving the password in cookies / localStorage.

Make sure the `uname` and `password` variables are not hard-coded into the source code. Those should be passed by user input via form.

As long as the password is only in memory, you should be safe if you protect yourself from XSS attacks.

I also strongly encourage you to use HTTPS connection to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I do have an HTTPS connection in place. I'll read more about how to make sure that cookies don't store passwords. Thanks again.

Comment: @90abyss, a cookie won't store password if you do not tell it to do so. Most likely it will store the session ID, but this is also something you will not avoid.

As long as the important piece of information is not explicitly put into the source code accessible by unwanted parties or this piece of information is not stored in some permanent or semi-permanent storage (like cookies), you should be safe.

Please note, there is much more to web app security that this.